# How to TRANSPOSE this data in Google sheet for importhtml

Tags: arrays, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have data on a Google sheet. my importhtml formula get data in my sheet like this

Sheet one

```
    Column A |             | Column B
    =================================
   Name 1    |             | Tom
   Name 2    |             | Dim
```

Want to data in this format

```
    Column A |  Column B   | Column C | Column D
    ===========================================
   Name 1    |  Tom        | Name 2   |Dim  
             |             |          |
```

Or in this format

```
    Column A |  Column B   | Column C | Column D
    ===========================================
   Name 1    |  Name 2     | Tom      |Dim  
             |             |          |
```

Please help me to archive data in a format in  anyone from above

I try this but don't get format as I want

```
=TRANSPOSE(Importhtml(E1, "table",1))
```

Comment: can you share the content of E1?

Comment: its url in E1 from where i get data in my sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={TRANSPOSE(A2:A3), TRANSPOSE(B2:B3)}
```

[image: 0]

and that would be:

```
={TRANSPOSE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 1),,1)), 
  TRANSPOSE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 1),,2))}
```

Answer (score 2):

or:

```
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, A:B), "♦")
```

[image: 0]

and that would be:

```
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 1)), "♦")
```